# How to get the iOS devices camera name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, playback, avcapturedevice

Does IOS capture devices and playback devices have any name or path? Usually we can able to get path for connected camera and its name in windows, I guess in Mac also we can do that. Anyone have idea about how to get name and path of capture and playback devices on IOS?

```
  // RETURNS HOW MANY AUDIO CAPTURE DEVICES ARE THERE... 
  for eg: [[AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] count];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];
AVCaptureDevice *frontCamera;
AVCaptureDevice *backCamera;

for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {

    NSLog(@"Device name: %@", [device localizedName]);

    if ([device hasMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {

        if ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack) {
            NSLog(@"Device position : back");
            backCamera = device;
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Device position : front");
            frontCamera = device;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you get device name follwing method

```
NSString *name =[[UIDevice currentDevice] name]);
```

Comment: Iphone have two camera (front and back) which one it will return?

Comment: its give you device name not camera type.

Comment: Devices I meant here capture devices name.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, "devices" is deprecated in iOS 10.0.  Use AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession instead.